# Woocommerce cart update failure

Tags: woocommerce

When I add a product to my cart, I see the product added via Ajax. Nothing wrong. 
When I go to the previous page, my shopping cart is back empty until I refresh the page. I'm using FF or Safari. I don't have this problem in google Chrome (Cart shows the items I added, also when I go to the previous page. 
I have a basic up-to-date wordpress installation without any plugings activated. Have this problem in several themes. This sounds like a caching problem. Anyone with a solution? I do not have any custom code, this are all options from the standard woocommerce installation.